# Ignore/drop columns while left_join

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to merge/join 2 table by method = "Left"
Now i need to ignore few column before joining the tables as my df's are huge in size.

[image]

I have tried to ignore columns after joining the table which leads to preformance issue

```
Final_df = Left_df.merge(Right_df, left_on=['ID'], how='left', right_on=['ID'])
Final_df.drop(['Gender', 'Emp_Type'], axis = 1)
```

[image]

Instead of above method,Can we ignore those 2 columns from the right table while joining.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Final_df = Left_df.merge(Right_df.drop(['Gender', 'Emp_Type'], axis = 1), left_on=['ID'], how='left', right_on=['ID'])` ??

Answer (score 3):

You could either slice or drop before joining:

```
Final_df = Left_df.merge(Right_df[['ID', 'City', 'Country']],
                         left_on=['ID'], how='left', right_on=['ID'])
```

or

```
Final_df = Left_df.merge(Right_df.drop(['Gender', 'Emp_Type'], axis = 1),
                         left_on=['ID'], how='left', right_on=['ID'])
```